# rundll32.exe not working on windows 2003 server

Tags: windows, forms, oracle

I used following command on windows xp and its working perfectly fine.

```
 rundll32.exe url.dll,FileProtocolHandler c:\test.pdf
```

but the same command is doing nothing at all on windows 2003 server (precisely, Windows 2003 R2, Enterprise Edition, SP-2). My requirement actually is to open pdf documents saved on local disks from with in oracle form6i for which i intent to use

```
HOST('cmd /c rundll32.exe url.dll, FileProtocolHandler "c:\test.pdf"');
```

command, which is not working offcourse. The point is, if a command is not working on the dos shell in the first place, how will that run from oracle forms. So plz help me how to run this command on windows 2003? why the same command opens pdf perfectly fine on xp but not on 2003?

Thanks.

Comment: You have an extra space in the `/c` switch...

Comment: Thanks for reply. the exact command i used in the oracle forms was with correct syntax i.e HOST('cmd /c rundll32.exe url.dll, FileProtocolHandler "c:\test.pdf"');
the problem is that this command "rundll32.exe url.dll,FileProtocolHandler c:\test.pdf" runs on windows xp command prompt but do not run on windows 2003 server command prompt. Once it run on shell, it will run in forms too.

Comment: Any reason not to use the `start` command, `HOST("start 'c:\test.pdf'");`? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755674%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: you mean sir i can use host("start 'c:\test.pdf'"); in my oracle forms button_pressed trigger? on windows 2003 server and it would work?

Comment: It is worth a try - `start` is the standard way to launch a file in the application it is associated with.

Comment: u got me sir. i am just going to server to try it out. thanks.

Comment: start worked. sir plz add your comment as answer so that i should check it correct :)

Comment: Nice to hear! I have written a more elaborate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call `cmd /c rundll32.exe url.dll, FileProtocolHandler "c:\test.pdf"` looks like you are trying to display a pdf file with the default viewer of the system.

There is a command that does this, and it has been around at least since Windows 95: [start](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755674%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). Just run `start "c:\test.pdf"` and the system will launch the file with the associated program.

From `help start`:

> non-executable files may be invoked through their file association just
>       by typing the name of the file as a command.  (e.g.  WORD.DOC would
>       launch the application associated with the .DOC file extension).
>       See the ASSOC and FTYPE commands for how to create these
>       associations from within a command script.